# How to break a bar chart when the data is to high in difference of the others in plotlyJS?

Tags: javascript, charts, plotly, bar-chart, plotly.js

so i have this simple bar chart in plotlyJS, and it was requested that when a bar is higher compared to the other, it has to break to not display the entire bar, so that it does not shrink the others.

This is a simple image of my chart, i don't put the code because you know plotly has kind the same structure for all the charts.

[image: My bar chart]

And what i want to do is this is if is possible

[image: What i want to accomplished]

Any information would help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to do with Plotly.js at the moment.

Comment: oh well, i have to find something else, thank you so much